# PostgreSQL indexes creation time

Tags: postgresql, ddl

what is the query that i can use to find out when(date) a particular index (unique or non-unique) has been created in the database. Basically i want to find out the indexes that were created in the last one month or so.

Comment: You can get the relfilenode for the index from the system catalogs and examine the ctime of the on-disk file that backs the index. However (a) I think `REINDEX` will delete and recreate it, and (b) for big indexes there can be more than one such file as they're in 1GB chunks. I'm curious: *why* do you want that?

Comment: The best thing to do is to keep `log_statement` on to at least log DDL, so you can trace such events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. There is no info about creating time of relations, indexes, ...